# Xamarin.Forms untappable ListView (remove selection ripple effect)

Tags: c#, android, xaml, listview, xamarin.forms

I have a ListView with a custom ViewCell that displays articles. However when you select a item, it shows the material design ripple/selection effect.

[image: Ripple effect]

**Xaml:**

```
   <ListView HasUnevenRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding NewsArticles}" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
              <StackLayout Padding="10">
                <Label Text="{Binding Title}" HorizontalOptions="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" IsVisible="{Binding HasImage}" />
                <Label Text="{Binding Content}"></Label>
              </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
          </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
      </ListView>
```

How do I remove the ripple effect?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

So after a long, long time we figured it out, you can accomplish it with a custom renderer. Here is how,

First, create a file called **no_selector.xml** and place it in the Resources/layouts folder (the packaging properties must be set to AndroidResource).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>
</selector>
```

After that create a custom renderer for the ListView component,

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof(ListView), typeof(NoRippleListViewRenderer))]
namespace Your.Own.Namespace
{
    public class NoRippleListViewRenderer : ListViewRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<ListView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged (e);
            Control.SetSelector (Resource.Layout.no_selector);
        }
    }
}
```

*If the `no_selector` file can't be found rebuild your project!*

Be aware of the fact that this removes the ripple for **all** the ListViews in your application. If you only want it to target a couple you can change the first type on the ExportRenderer attribute (this does require you to make a separate class that extends ListView).

https://gist.github.com/awatertrevi/d83787dbbf3de6ef0e0a344169d3c2fa

Comment: We tried to do it exactly like this, but receiving a NotFoundException. We rebuild and cleaned the solution multiple times. The BuildAction is set to AndroidResources and we can see the xml-File in the generated APK

Comment: Bravo sir! Works flawlessly.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can remove it without a custom renderer.

You can set the `BackgroundColor` of your `StackPanel` to grey or whatever your list's or page's background color is.

```
<ListView HasUnevenRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding NewsArticles}" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout Padding="10" BackgroundColor="Gray">
                    <!-- ... --> 
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

---

Or you can use android styles to change the list view styles:

Set theme in **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application android:label="$safeprojectname$" android:theme="@style/myTheme"></application>
```

Create theme in **styles.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
    <style name="myTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light">
        <item name="android:listViewStyle">@style/ListViewStyle.Light</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ListViewStyle.Light" parent="@android:style/Widget.ListView">
        <item name="android:listSelector">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```