# Can I change the background color in ListView cells without losing haptic (touch) feedback?

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

*(I asked on the [Xamarin forums](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/73821/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-in-listview-cells-without-losing-haptic-touch-feedback#latest) but didn't get a response, so I'm trying here)*

In Xamarin Forms, setting `BackgroundColor` in a ListView `ItemTemplate` [causes haptic-feedback to be disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36255159/238419).

**Is there any way around this?**  I'd like to customize the colors of my list-items, but not having haptic feedback looks like garbage.

Example XAML:

```
 <ListView x:Name="list"
           ItemTapped="OnItemSelected"
           IsGroupingEnabled="True"
           GroupDisplayBinding="{Binding Key}"
           GroupShortNameBinding="{Binding Key}"
           HasUnevenRows="True"
           ItemsSource="{Binding .}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
              <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                           Padding="5, 20"
                           BackgroundColor="#CCCCCC"> <!--This line causes haptic feedback to fail -->
                <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                       TextColor="Black"
                       VerticalOptions="Center"
                       FontSize="Large"/>
              </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The closest I've gotten is changing the `BackgroundColor` in `ViewCell.Tapped`, then changing it back in `View.OnAppearing()` *(`ViewCell.Appearing` is broken)*, but that changes the background when the finger is lifted, rather than when it's pressed.

I'm testing on Android but would prefer a cross-platform solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check your post on the Xamarin forum for my feedback. I have an easy drop-in solution for you called XFGloss. Its a free open source add-on for Xamarin.Forms. The source is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/tbaggett/xfgloss). There is also a [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ansuria.XFGloss/) available. It allows you to assign a BackgroundColor value to the standard XF cell controls (TextCell, EntryCell, etc.). There are several other new properties also added by XFGloss.

If you prefer to fix your existing implementation, you can review the changes I made to support the visual feedback in this [code commit](https://github.com/tbaggett/xfgloss/commit/ec78d50deee8f5d89d8cd80febd454761eabb084#diff-74d3b2eec0eebc2c63d42f23f9118ccfR236).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13468494)

Comment: Apologies, Robert. I've edited my response to contain the answer by linking to the code commit where I fixed the same issue in my implementation that he was asking about.

Comment: I still haven't gotten a chance to try it, but I'll mark this as accepted for now.  Congratulations on the bounty, and welcome to stackoverflow!

Comment: Just an update: It worked exactly as advertised!  Thank you so much, Tommy!

Comment: Awesome, that's great news! Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 2):

**Once you set the Background color then you won't get to see the selected item color or Haptic feedback unless you create a custom render on each platform.**

Here is the work around you can implement which is cross platform and MVVM based using Bindings for setting the color of selected item:

1. Bind a property to the `SelectedItem` of `ListView`.
2. Bind the Background color of your `StackLayout` to an auto property and set the value of "#CCCCCC" if its not selected item else some other color.
3. You need to subscribe to the SelectedMyItem property in the `MyItem` class and invoke `OnPropertyChanged` of BackgroundColor property. For this you can raise an event and subscribe or anything that you feel comfortable.*(this is not implemented in the sample pseudo code provided below)*

ViewModel :

```
public class MyViewModel : IMyViewModel
{
    public ObserveableCollection<MyItem> Items { get; set; }
    public MyItem SelectedMyItem { get; set; }
}
```

List item class :

```
public class MyItem 
{
    private readonly IMyViewModel _myViewModel;

    public MyItem(IMyViewModel myViewModel)
    {
        _myViewModel = myViewModel;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Color BackgroundColor => _myViewModel.SelectedMyItem == this 
                                    ? Color.Red : Color.FromHex("CCCCCC");        
}
```

XAML :

```
<ListView x:Name="list"
           IsGroupingEnabled="True"
           GroupDisplayBinding="{Binding Key}"
           GroupShortNameBinding="{Binding Key}"
           HasUnevenRows="True"
           ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
           SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMyItem}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
              <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                           Padding="5, 20"
                           BackgroundColor="{Binding BackgroundColor}">
                   <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                       <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnItemTapped" />
                   </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                       TextColor="Black"
                       VerticalOptions="Center"
                       FontSize="Large"/>
              </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Haptic feedback work around :

Usually a touch is 200-300ms. Once an item is tapped you can change the color of the background for that much duration and then set to the original color.

```
public async void OnItemTapped(object sender, EventArgs args) 
{
   BackgroundColor = Color.Orange; //touch color
   await Task.Delay(250);          //time to show new color
   BackgroundColor = Color.Red;    //original color
}
```

You can even improve this further by trying to incorporate [animations](https://blog.xamarin.com/creating-animations-with-xamarin-forms/), maybe the [FadeTo](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.ViewExtensions.FadeTo/p/Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement/System.Double/System.UInt32/Xamarin.Forms.Easing/) for changing colors.

Comment: This changes the background of the selected item, which is not the same as haptic feedback.  Even if you set the background color back after a short time _(like in the simpler suggestion in the question)_, it still changes the background after the finger is lifted rather than pressed, which doesn't feel right.

Comment: i have added a work around for the haptic feedback too. If you need perfect implementation its always better to create a custom render. You can check out the existing implementation from github and extend it.

Comment: That workaround is exactly what I mentioned in the question and my above comment...

Comment: Then the answer is No to your question, unless you are ready to do it via Custom renderer.

Answer (score 0):

**You can simply use this in your Viewcell inherited class**,

`this.Tapped += ViewCell_Tapped;`  // By using tapped in your viewcell you can achieve like haptic.

> private async void ViewCell_Tapped(object sender,
>   EventArgs e)
>           {
>               this.View.BackgroundColor = Color.Gray;
>               await Task.Delay(10);
>               this.View.BackgroundColor = Color.White;
>           }

**This is working for me.**

Comment: In the question, it already says *"The closest I've gotten is changing the BackgroundColor in ViewCell.Tapped, then changing it back in View.OnAppearing() ..., but that changes the background when the finger is lifted, rather than when it's pressed."*