# Disable selecting Items in ListView

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

For a Social Networking app I am working on I am trying to display comments with a ListView but I do not want it to be highlighted when clicked.

I tried using

```
`((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null;` in a selected event but that still shows it being selected for a second. I need it to never show.
```

I also tried setting the List View to

`IsEnabled="False"`

also tried putting it in the View Cell but that causes the buttons and click events to not work.

Comment: @mjwills Edited some detail in

Comment: did you checked similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343793/how-to-disable-highlighting-on-listbox-but-keep-selection)

Comment: @RahulAgarwal That didn't help much, I used (iOS) https://montemagno.com/adding-a-disclosure-indicator-accessory-to/ and (Android) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35586243/xamarin-forms-untappable-listview-remove-selection-ripple-effect/36225591#36225591 which worked perfectly

Comment: If you have solved your problem make your own answer, add the details of why it worked for you and mark your answer as correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Android:**

I created a custom renderer for ListView and set

```
Control.SetSelector(Android.Resource.Color.Transparent);
```

**iOS:**

I created a custom ViewCell renderer and set

```
cell.SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None;
```

**References:**

Android:  [Xamarin.Forms untappable ListView (remove selection ripple effect)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35586243/xamarin-forms-untappable-listview-remove-selection-ripple-effect/36225591#36225591)

iOS: https://montemagno.com/adding-a-disclosure-indicator-accessory-to/

Comment: Learning how to use a code section would surely improve your answers with minimum overhead.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this,

```
myListView.ItemTapped += (object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e) => {    
   if (e.Item == null) return;     
    ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null; 
 };
```

Comment: It is still highlighting for a second, and if held down it stays highlighted

Comment: it seems to be a bug , try with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35586243/xamarin-forms-untappable-listview-remove-selection-ripple-effect/36225591#36225591

Comment: I used "Control.SetSelector(Android.Resource.Color.Transparent);" for android which seems to work

Comment: great! i have not done much xamarin, i was helping you with the existing answers

Comment: Just need to find a iOS fix though

Comment: check these links https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26657932/how-to-disable-highlight-on-listview-in-xamarin-forms

Comment: for IOS https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/50783/how-i-can-disable-highlight-item-in-listview

Comment: @Daniel This is trying to solve the problem after the fact, youre racing the UI, the only way to solve this is by creating a non selectable renderer

Comment: I used `Control.SetSelector(Android.Resource.Color.Transparent);` for Android and `cell.SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None;` for iOS, which worked perfectly.